# Style issue in the picker

Tags: codenameone

I've set the uiid of a picker in the theme. The font is set in millimeter (2.5) for all unselected, selected and pressed.It works fine. But when I use setEnabled(false), the font style changes and is bigger. P.S I've set same font and same font size for unselected, selected and pressed in the theme. How can I make it work?

```
Picker stationPicker = new Picker();
stationPicker.setEnabled(false); //without this line, it works fine
stationPicker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
stationPicker.setSelectedString("Select the service center");
stationPicker.setUIID("small");
stationPicker.getAllStyles().setMarginLeft(1);
stationPicker.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xcccccc);
```

when setEnabled isnot used

[image]

Img when setEnabled is used

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another UIID: Disabled.

When you set enabled to false the disabled UIID takes over.